# Table tennis raw data organisation in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need **to output with a single formula the data from column A** (highlighted in purple) **in a way that organizes it in the same way as the N-Y columns I made manually for the sample** (highlighted in green). Below is the list of claims that the final formula must contain within itself.

1. **League** Column. Output the cell located above cell "1"
2. Columns **Game, Time, Home, Away**. All cells with a dash " - "
   and the three cells following the " - "
3. Columns **F1, F2**. First 5 digits and last 4 digits from the 4th cell after " - " (for F2 from the 5th cell after " - ").
4. Columns **T, T1, T2** - 6,7,8, cells after " - "

File link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19Ro8J7ySxTrN9NLqvpG25BXgyLPpyYAhx1YsPhDc-eA/edit#gid=1401312864

[image]

Comment: What are you having trouble with?

Comment: I transformed column A data to sample in N-Y columns manually, now I need to do it automatically with formula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Here's one approach](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19Ro8J7ySxTrN9NLqvpG25BXgyLPpyYAhx1YsPhDc-eA/edit#gid=1601241710) you may test out:*

```js
=filter({scan(,iferror(A1:A1023),lambda(a,c,if(regexmatch(c&"","РОССИЯ. ЛИГА ПРО"),c,a))),A1:A1023, A2:A1024, A3:A1025, A4:A1026,
         regexextract(map(A5:A1027,lambda(Σ,iferror(Σ,formulatext(Σ)))),"=?(.*?\.\d)(.*)"),
         regexextract(map(A6:A1028,lambda(Σ,iferror(Σ,formulatext(Σ)))),"=?(.*?\.\d)(.*)"),
         A7:A1029, A8:A1030, A9:A1031},
 regexmatch(A1:A1023,"—"))
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, buddy, I've been waiting for you. Thank you so much.